# RTF increase font size with a factor with regex

Tags: c#, regex, rtf

I have to increase all the fonts in an RTF string with a factor.

The font size is defined as e.g.  `\fs120`  (would mean 60 pt) in the RTF string.

How can in go through all font sizes in the RTF string and multiply it with a factor to replace the original value with the new calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this as C#:

```
Regex.Replace(input,
              @"\\fs([0-9]+)\b",
              m => string.Format(@"\fs{0}", int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) * 2));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/qE3JHO)

The used pattern is: `\\fs([0-9]+)\b`. It matches the font size construct and captures the size. The `Replace` function simply replaces the matched string by a new value using a callback that doubles the font size.